# UWP and DirectX

Tags: c#, c++, directx, win-universal-app

I have a task:

> 'Second component must be written in C++ and must be a UWP assembly/component that will be used by the First part of the task. It must be a DirectX component that draws to SwapChain with transparent background. The content must be a 2D animation that must be bound to current mouse position. The content must be controllable via set of public methods.
>
> DirectX component must be placed on top of your C# GUI so it will act as overlay.
> Make it event-transparent overlay, it must not capture any GUI events and otherwise interfere with C# app.
> Use C# host to send mouse events and content change to DX layer.'

But I have no idea how to combine UWP and DirectX.
I already have functioning UWP C# app part and what's next?

I'll be grateful for any responces and ideas.

Comment: Look there: http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c-/84234-external-directx-overlay-translated.html - there's a simple example of how to write to any region of the directx device. About capturing the mouse events  - you need to listen to WM_MOUSE*** types of events in your WinMain function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a **SwapChainPanel** or **SwapChainBackgroundPanel** control into your XAML file. This surface will be used to draw your DirectX content. You have a default uwp sample in **Visual C++ Template** named DirectX 11 and XAML App. It can help you to understand the plumbing but there is only C++ code on this solution.

Comment: They are describing XAML+C# code-behind with a SwapChainPanel or  SwapChainBackgroundPanel control which can be rendered to with DirectX. There's no built-in C# support for DirectX, but you can use a 3rd party assembly like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). The built-in Visual C++ template "DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows)" does this for C++ code-behind, but there's not a built-in template for C# code-behind combined with DirectX.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) which is a C# wrapper for Direct2D, and in particular the [Win2D Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples) repository.

Answer (score 1):

MonoGame!

It's a game framework, based on XNA4 that works on UWP, among a myriad of other platforms. You can pick apart the samples to learn what you need.

http://www.monogame.net/